# Replace all autocad shortcuts found on system ussing Batch?

Tags: batch-file, replace, shortcut, lnk

I need to replace every icon (AutoCAD 2010.LNK) found on the computer with another .LNK using batch.

The icon\ shortcut as we well know can be found anywhere and as many times as the user likes.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, read `HELP FOR`

and then try this in a command line

```
  FOR /F "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /B /S "AUTOCAD 2010.LNK"') do ECHO COPY new.lnk %a
```

experiment with from various locations and test carefully

then create a bat file with the following contents. Note the change of %a into %%a and the removal of the 'echo'

```
@echo off
PUSHD C:\
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /B /S "AUTOCAD 2010.LNK"') do COPY new.lnk %%a
POPD
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "linklist=%USERPROFILE%\linklist.txt"
SET "replacement=D:\path\to\replacement.lnk"
ECHO Searching...
DIR /B /S "C:\AutoCAD 2010.LNK" >%linklist%
DIR /B /S "D:\AutoCAD 2010.LNK" >>%linklist%
:: add similar rows for every drive letter you want to be included
ECHO Replacing...
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f IN (%linklist%) DO COPY %replacement% %%f
ECHO Finished.
```

A couple of notes:

- Your replacement shortcut file **must** be named differently (like `AutoCAD 2010.LNK.new`, for example).
- In Windows Vista/7 you will probably be prohibited from overwriting files in certain folders unless you are running the script with elevated rights.